# Using BeatifulSoup to scrape pdfs from a specific website

Tags: python-3.x, recaptcha, knime

guys.

First of all, I'm not a python programmer at all. I fidgeted with ChatGPT 3.5 for a while to come up with all the code, and occasionaly I manually made fixes to the code, as I troubleshooted.

The goal is to download pdf bills from my local water supply company's client web portal, which is usually done manually. I'm planning on running a KNIME workflow to run the python code when needed. I thought that the code could enter the credentials, and I manually solve the reCaptcha on a Chrome webdriver. Once it's solved, it should automatically closes and the code do the rest, which is navigate to the bills' page, identifying if there's one or more bill to be downloaded, access the URL and save each individual bill on the pre-defined directory. Then, it should repeat for each credential (which is the hydrometer number, plus a password), as I administer 3 hydrometers.

I came up with this, but I cannot pass the login page, and I have no idea which token is missing or what is the problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from getpass import getpass
import re
import os
import datetime
import knime.scripting.io
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# set login credentials
users = [{'usuario': 'user1', 'senha': 'pass1'},
         {'usuario': 'user2', 'senha': 'pass2'},
         {'usuario': 'user3', 'senha': 'pass3'}]

# set directory to save PDFs
directory = r"D:\OneDrive\Documentos à lançar\Faturas"

# create directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

# login to website and download PDFs
for user in users:
    # create session object
    session = requests.Session()

    # Open a new tab using Chrome webdriver and disable AutomationControlled
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("https://atvn.sanepar.com.br/login")

    # Wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(2)

    # Wait for the reCaptcha to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="reCAPTCHA"]')))

    # Switch to the iframe containing the reCaptcha
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@title="reCAPTCHA"]')
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    # Wait for the reCaptcha to be ready
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"][@aria-checked="true"]')))

    # Check if the reCaptcha has been solved
    while True:
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@aria-checked="true"]'):
            break
        time.sleep(1)

    # Switch back to the default content
    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    # send login request with user credentials
    login_url = "https://atvn.sanepar.com.br/login"
    response = session.get(login_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    token_elem = soup.find('input', {'usuario': '_token'})
    if token_elem is not None:
        token = token_elem['value']
    else:
        print("Error: could not find CSRF token")
        continue  # skip to next user
    payload = {'_token': token,
               'tipoacesso': 'matricula',  # add token here
               'usuario': user['usuario'],
               'senha': user['senha']}
    response = session.post(login_url, data=payload)

    # check if login was successful
    if 'Login ou senha inválidos' in response.text:
        print(f"Login failed for user {user['usuario']}")
        continue

    # get all URLs that start with 'https://atvn.sanepar.com.br/segundavia/PDF/'
    main_url = "https://site.sanepar.com.br/servicos/segunda-via"
    response = session.get(main_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    pdf_links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("^https://atvn.sanepar.com.br/segundavia/PDF/"))

    # download all PDFs
    download_count = 1
    for link in pdf_links:
        pdf_url = link.get('href')
        filename = pdf_url.split('/')[-1]
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
        download_count_str = str(download_count).zfill(3)
        new_filename = f"{timestamp}_{download_count_str}_Sanepar_{user['usuario'].replace('_', ' ')}.pdf"

        # check if file already exists with the same name for this user on this date
        while os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, new_filename)):
            download_count += 1
            download_count_str = str(download_count).zfill(3)
            new_filename = f"{timestamp}_{download_count_str}_Sanepar_{user['usuario'].replace('_', ' ')}.pdf"

        filepath = os.path.join(directory, new_filename)
        response = session.get(pdf_url)
        with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print(f"Downloaded {new_filename}")
        download_count += 1

    # log out of session
    logout_url = "https://atvn.sanepar.com.br/Login/Sair"
    session.get(logout_url)
```